# use the filter defined in html, in my angular controller

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-filter

I am using a text box in which user can enter any text.
based on that the items in the list shown below are filtered as soon as text is typed/erased...

select all(send everyone there) removes the items from mainlist and adds those elements to selected list...

works fine for all. i want that only the filtered ones should be moved from one list to another...(on select all, all items are transferred!)

can i pass the same text(entered by user) and use that as a filter on my list inside the angular controller??

if yes, then guide me how.

below is the code segment :

```js
$scope.transferList = function ( x ) {
  if ( x === "selectAllServers" ) {
   for ( i = 0; i < $scope.lists.serversList.servers.length; i++ ) {
    $scope.lists.selectedServersList.servers.push(   $scope.lists.serversList.servers[ i ] );
   }
   $scope.lists.serversList.servers = [];
          }
  };
```

```html
<div class="text-center">
  <h3>Select Servers</h3>
 </div>
 <div class="container col-md-4 col-md-offset-1">
  <form>
     <div class="form-group">
         <div class="input-group style='width: 100%'">
           <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-filter"></i></div>
           <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter text to filter servers..." ng-model="searchTerm">
         </div>      
      </div>
  </form>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="box col-md-4 col-md-offset-1">
   <ul dnd-list="lists.serversList.servers"
    dnd-allowed-types="lists.serversList.allowedTypes">
    <li class="text-center">Servers Available</li>
    <li ng-repeat="server in lists.serversList.servers|filter:searchTerm"
     dnd-draggable="server" dnd-type="server.type"
     dnd-disable-if="server.type == 'unknown'"
     dnd-moved="lists.serversList.servers.splice($index, 1)"
     dnd-effect-allowed="move" class="background-unselected"
     class="searchable">
     <div class="handle">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"
       ng-click="selectItem('server',$index)"></i>
     </div>
     <div class="name">{{server.name}}</div>
    </li>
    <li class="dndPlaceholder">Drop <strong>server</strong> here
    </li>
   </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="box col-md-4 col-md-offset-2">
   <ul dnd-list="lists.selectedServersList.servers"
    dnd-allowed-types="lists.selectedServersList.allowedTypes">
    <li class="text-center">Servers Selected</li>
    <li ng-repeat="server in lists.selectedServersList.servers"
     dnd-draggable="server" dnd-type="server.type"
     dnd-disable-if="server.type == 'unknown'"
     dnd-moved="lists.selectedServersList.servers.splice($index, 1)"
     dnd-effect-allowed="move" class="background-selected">
     <div class="handle">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"
       ng-click="removeItem('server',$index)"></i>
     </div>
     <div class="name">{{server.name}}</div>
    </li>
    <li class="dndPlaceholder">Drop <strong>server</strong> here
    </li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
 <br />
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1">
   <button class="btn btn-default btn-block"
    ng-click="transferList('selectAllServers')">
    Send Everyone there <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></i>
   </button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-2">
   <button class="btn btn-default btn-block"
    ng-click="transferList('unSelectAllServers')">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left"></i> Send Everyone there
   </button>
  </div>
 </div>
```

hope the code is readable enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.You can launch same filter:

```
$scope.add = function() {
    var filtered = $filter('filter')($scope.lists.serversList.servers, $scope.searchTerm);
    // actual add here
}
```

2.As you see there is some code duplication here - you use same filter twice, so you can rewrite a bit:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter text to filter servers..." ng-model="searchTerm" ng-change="recalculateFiltered()">
<li ng-repeat="server in filteredList" ...
```

And in controller:

```
$scope.recalculateFiltered = function() {
        $scope.filteredList = $filter('filter')($scope.lists.serversList.servers, $scope.searchTerm);
}
```

Comment: thanks....i am trying this.
also can i use this filter (searchTerm) too retrieve all except those that match the filter??

Comment: ['name1', 'name2', 'qwe'] | filter : '!name' -> ['qwe']